# SQL order address by house number

Tags: mysql, sql

So if I have results

```
11 The street
9 The street 
59 The street
```

A regular `ORDER BY ASC` does this

```
11 The street
59 The street 
9 The street
```

How can I order by `ASC` and have the numbers count up like

```
9 The street
11 The street 
59 The street
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select *
From tbl
order by cast(Left(Col, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', Col)) as int)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e488a/1)

For MySql, please try:

```
select *
From tbl
order by convert(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col, ' ', 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

[MySql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73593/10)

Comment: +1. I think he would want to sort by adress then number, though. Suggested edit: `select *
From tbl
order by Substring(Col, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', Col), 999),
         cast(Left(Col, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', Col)) as int)
         `

Comment: @TechDo thanks I'm having trouble isolating the name of the street though now, to order by street name then number, The SUBSTRING_INDEX function doesn't seem capable of going right from a left starting point. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81a1d/1

Comment: @user1209203, maybe you should post that as an edit to the question? You don't mention needing to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (bit simple); just going by your sample data and assuming that all your data string have `The Street` common in them. Else, what TechDo have suggested should be the One I will go for (For a generic solution)

```
select * from tbl
order by 
cast(
(substring(col,0,charindex('The street',col))) as int)
```