# SQL Query (sort street address)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of street addresses that I want to sort in the following order:

- Street 1
- Street 27 A
- Street 27 F
- Street 30 D
- Street 31 D
- Street 205
- Street 207 B

When I do a simple `order by` street, I get:

```
Street 1, Street 205, Street 207 B, Street 27 A, Street 27 F, Street 30 D, Street 30 D
```

and that is not what I want.

I can't find any good example out there, here is one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339278/sql-order-address-by-house-number) but this is the opposite.

Comment: What database are you uisng?

Comment: You'll need to part out the number value cast it to a numeric value and then sort by the text street name then the number.

Comment: It's almost impossible to get something coherent, as you may perfectly have a number in the `name` of the street. The best way to go would be to separate 1. Street name 2. HouseNumber 3. HouseNumberComplement

Comment: @GordonLinoff i'm using mysql

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: can you provide a example how the query would look like

Comment: Well, if you separate your data into 3 fields (StreetName varchar, HouseNumber int, HouseNumberComplement varchar), you could simply do `order by StreetName, HouseNumber, HouseNumberComplement`

Answer (score 2):

Consider you have organized your address table in two columns `road` and `house_number` (the latter with complements) the following query (PostgreSQL) does the trick (order addresses for a distinct road 'The Road'):

```
SELECT road, house_number from address_table
WHERE road = 'The Road'
ORDER BY CAST(regexp_replace(house_number, '[[:alpha:]]', '') AS INTEGER),
         regexp_replace(house_number, '[[:digit:]]', '')
```

There seem to be approaches to replace using regular expression with MySQL too: [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER_BY your_Order * 1 ASC
```

will convert it to a number since it seems to be a text value.

Check the table definition and change it. You can change the data type to int like this

```
ALTER TABLE your_Table MODIFY COLUMN registration_no int;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns all start with a single word (such as `'Street'`) followed by a space and a number, then you can do:

```
order by substring_index(streetaddress, ' ', 2) + 0
```

This will convert the second "word" in the address to a number which is used for sorting.

If your real data is different from the sample data, I would suggest that you ask another question with appropriate examples of what your data really looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this not work for me, i already got a solution.
Going to separate the street-address in 3 values

Answer (score -1):

Try this

With addresses as

```
(
SELECT 
Address1, 
Postcode,
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(Address1), 1, 1)) = 1 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS StartsWithNumber,
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(Address1), 1, 1)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Address1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Address1)) END AS housenumber
FROM youttable )
```

Select Address1 from addresses

order by StartsWithNumber asc, housenumber, Address1