# Search in multiple columns Android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need help with a search query for a android app, I'm using sqlite.
Before it easy to search for a street name because i had only one column to search from, I did this to fix the sort by query [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245121/sql-querysort-street-address).

i have a database with the following rows and columns:

```
id  street_name   street_number   sub_number 
1   PIERPONTWEG        25             
2   PIERPONTWEG        45             B     
3   PIERPONTWEG        77             
4   SARKIWEG           45             A    
5   SARKIWEG           13                 
6   SARKIWEG           5                 
7   ALIBAKSWEG         5                 
8   SHANTIWEG          44             A          
9   SHANTIWEG          44             B       
10  SHANTIWEG          44             C
```

I have a only one search box where i search for a street name for example 'SHANTIWEG 44' and want the following results:'SHANTIWEG 44 A','SHANTIWEG 44 B','SHANTIWEG 44 C'.

Comment: you can use **LIKE** operator.

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Street_Name = 'SHANTIWEG' AND Street_Number = 44`

Comment: show your table Structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings (with the [operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) `||`), but there will be no index in use.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE street_name||" "||street_number LIKE 'SHANTIWEG 44%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i get no results for that

Comment: @Gilbert92 maybe there's some whitespace in the values to trim. You could check with something like `SELECT street_name||"-"||street_number||"-"`, just to verify it.

Comment: @m.chinni thanks it works, had to remove the whitespace.
going to change the LIKE 'SHANTIWEG 44%' to LIKE '%SHANTIWEG 44%'

Comment: @Gilbert92 Maybe you should trim the values before inserting them in the table, so you keep the data normalized.